# error while using lkl keylogger in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line

I got this error when I am in a way to compile "lkl keylogger" from terminal.

```
rohit@rohit-Vostro-15-3568:~/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl$ make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rohit/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl'
/bin/bash ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
  /usr/bin/install -c lkl /usr/local/bin/lkl
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/lkl': Permission denied
Makefile:153: recipe for target 'install-binPROGRAMS' failed
make[1]: *** [install-binPROGRAMS] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rohit/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl'
Makefile:318: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make: *** [install-am] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the user you're running as does not have the permissions necessary to install the file:

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/lkl': Permission denied
```

Run the `make install` as `root`, via:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: what happens to this......

Comment: root@rohit-Vostro-15-3568:/home/rohit/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl# sudo make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/rohit/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl'
/bin/bash ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/bin
  /usr/bin/install -c lkl /usr/local/bin/lkl
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rohit/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/Downloads/lkl'

Comment: again an  error in your command